# Action controller name with '-' in it

Tags: configuration, magento-1.9, url

I have a configuration which is as follows: Notification->ReviewControllor->IndexAction

So I can access this url via: notification/review/index or notification/review

I want to make this work in such a way that: notification/review-vote should work.

How to I write my actionController name such that 'review-vote' gets me to the IndexAction method?

Comment: Did you trying using a URL rewrite in the admin?

Answer (score 1):

You may add a custom router, so that this request will be handled by indexAction

See for example
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-router-in-magento/